# How to programatically remove sandbox attribute from an iframe with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I didn't think this was possible, however, i found this quote:

> ["It is strongly discouraged to use both allow-scripts and allow-same-origin at the same time, as that allows the embedded document to programmatically remove the sandbox attribute."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe)

My iframe needs to have a sandbox, but only when I am browsing in certain URLs where the embedded browsing context tries to navigate (load) content to the top-level browsing context (Jump out of frame...)

On other pages the sandbox needs to be removed entirely, as it wont allow me to browse away from a site with a different origin...

> The frame attempting navigation is sandboxed, and is therefore disallowed from navigating its ancestors.

Programatically changing the sandbox with :

```
document.getElementById("frame").sandbox = "";
```

...doesnt work either as this still places restrictions... Therefore, i need to somehow remove the attribute entirely, how would i go about doing this?

Comment: I would think you would just need to reset the iframe instead of changing the attribute. that means, delete the iframe and recreate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> These flags only take effect when the nested browsing context of the
>   iframe is navigated. Removing them, or removing the entire sandbox
>   attribute, has no effect on an already-loaded page.

More info - [**Here**](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-sandbox)

Comment: This page you linked me to says, "Setting both the allow-scripts and allow-same-origin keywords together when the embedded page has the same origin as the page containing the iframe allows the embedded page to simply remove the sandbox attribute and then reload itself, effectively breaking out of the sandbox altogether."

Comment: Yes, but the page need's to be from the same origin.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the sandbox attribute from the element using `iframe.removeAttribute("sandbox")` this will make the iframe non-sandboxed for the *next* content you load into it, not the currently loaded one.