# How can an iframe remove its own sandboxing?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe, browser

I'm using a same-origin iframe to load a foreign widget (tlk.io loaded through a cross-origin script). I'm trying to give the iframe/widget the lowest possible rights to isolate it from my app.

MDN gives the following warning:

> **Notes about sandboxing:**
>
> When the embedded document has the same origin as the embedding page, it is strongly discouraged to use both allow-scripts and allow-same-origin, as ***that lets the embedded document remove the sandbox attribute*** — making it no more secure than not using the sandbox attribute at all.

Firefox devtools show me this warning:

> An iframe which has both allow-scripts and allow-same-origin for its sandbox attribute ***can remove its sandboxing***.

My question is: in this situation (`sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"`) how could an iframe remove its sanboxing? What js code would perform this?

From the iframe, I tried looking at `window.opener` but it's null. `window.parent` is not referring to the parent (EDIT: NOT TRUE, I was using devtools wrongly). I can't find references to the «iframe» from the iframe itself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You open yourself up to DOM manipulation by the iframe.

With both of those sandbox attributes, there is nothing to stop the embedded frame from replacing itself with a new iframe. An iframe with whatever privilege's it wanted enabled.

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bad Sandboxing</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>This is here to space out iframe</p>
    <iframe
      src="malicious_child.html"
      sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
      id="mountPoint"
    >
    </iframe>
    <p>This is here to space out iframe</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

malicious_child.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Child</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.body.innerText = "Loaded into a frame.";

    let parent = window.parent;
    let oldIframe = parent.document.getElementById("mountPoint");
    if (oldIframe != null) {
        // Build a new iframe to replace the old one.
        let newIframe = parent.document.createElement("iframe");
        newIframe.setAttribute("src", "malicious_child.html");
        newIframe.setAttribute("id", "maliciousFrame");
        // Replace Old iFrame
        oldIframe.replaceWith(newIframe);
    } else {
        // When new frame is mounted you will see this alert
        alert(
            "This should not happen since the original iframe did not have 'allow-modals'."
        );
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's a [Code Sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/malicious-child-demo-8ckkw?file=/index.html) with this setup.

Comment: Interesting. So in my case, if my iframe 1st line of js is `window.parent = window` that should prevent the foreign script (tlk.io) from escaping the sandbox?

Comment: Possibly. You'd likely also have to obfuscate `window.top` as well.

Comment: You might also be able to use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to monitor for DOM changes and prevent your frame from being changed. See: [Is possible to detect a change in the DOM and make it not happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21975758/15497888)

Comment: Why go the hard way of replacing the iframe with an other one. Quite literally, the iframe "can remove its sandboxing." `oldIframe.removeAttribute("sandbox")`.

Comment: Sandbox "flags only take effect when the nested browsing context of the iframe element is navigated. Removing them, or removing the entire sandbox attribute, has no effect on an already-loaded page." [How to programatically remove sandbox attribute from an iframe with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16135465/15497888)

Comment: AFAICT, this only works if both pages are served from the same origin.
Otherwise, `parent.document` fails in the browser with an `Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object`.